# SugarCRM 7.9 - removing custom fields while uninstalling package

Tags: php, database, manifest, sugarcrm

I've created installable package, where I create some custom user fields through my manifest.php:

```
$installdefs = [
'custom_fields' => 
[...],
[...]
]
```

I've added post uninstall too:

```
    'post_uninstall' => [
    [
        0 => '<basepath>/post_uninstall.php'
    ]
]
```

In my post_uninstall.php I've added:

```
$fieldsByModule = array(
    'Users' => array(
        'field1_c',
        'field2_c',
        'field3_c',
        'field4_c',
        'field5_c',
        'field6_c'
        ),
    );

foreach ($fieldsByModule as $moduleName => $fields) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $dyField = new DynamicField();
        $dyField->bean = BeanFactory::getBean($moduleName);;
        $dyField->module = $moduleName;
        $dyField->deleteField($field);
    }
}
```

When I run post_uninstall script manually it works and remove fields from Sugar DB, but when I try to uninstall the package from Sugar ModuleLoader, uninstall process gets stuck at 76% (Rebuilding Platforms...), package files are removed but custom fields stay in DB.

My question is - how should I properly remove custom fields using post_uninstall.php. My way seems not to work. Or maybe there is some other way? The point is user should be able to uninstall the package(custom fields too) from admin panel.

Comment: What version are you running? I have no issues on 7.9.2.0, in fact, the module loader removes the fields on uninstall without need for a post_uninstall on that version. Can you share error log messages, and perhaps an example of the field you added in manifest.php?